Inability To Execute Specific Shell Command In Golang
I'm trying to execute program named "Commix" in Golang and retrieve the output. However, the tools exits with status code 0 after it parsed my HTTP request file. There are no indicators of failure. I haven't opened an issue on Commix's GitHub page because it does not seem to be a problem with the tool itself.
The following command is what I am tying to execute: commix -r req.txt --ignore-stdin --batch
Executing from my Linux terminal it yields the proper results, the request file has been parsed and the tool initiates testing for command injections.
The tool also performs as expected when run from Python (v3.12.3):
import subprocess
cmd = "commix -r req.txt --ignore-stdin --batch"
returned_value = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
print(returned_value)

However, using Golang (v1.22.2) the tool states it "[info] Parsing HTTP request..." then it exits with status code 0. Keep in mind that Commix is the only tool that behaves like this, other tools I execute work just fine.
Function I am using for executing shell commands in Golang:

func OsExec(command, wd string) (output string) {
    var (
        stdout, stderr string
        outbuf, errbuf bytes.Buffer
        exitCode       int
    )

    cmd := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", command)
    cmd.Dir = wd
    cmd.Env = os.Environ()

    cmd.Stdout = &outbuf
    cmd.Stderr = &errbuf

    err := cmd.Run()

    stdout = outbuf.String()
    stderr = errbuf.String()

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error executing command: %v", err)
        exitCode = getErrorExitCode(err)
    } else {
        exitCode = cmd.ProcessState.Sys().(syscall.WaitStatus).ExitStatus()
    }

    if stderr == "" && exitCode != 0 {
        stderr += err.Error()
    }

    output = strings.Join([]string{stdout, stderr, "Exit Status: " + strconv.Itoa(exitCode)}, "\n")
    output = strings.TrimPrefix(output, "\n")
    output = strings.TrimSuffix(output, "\n")

    return output
}

func getErrorExitCode(err error) int {
    if exitError, ok := err.(*exec.ExitError); ok {
        ws := exitError.Sys().(syscall.WaitStatus)
        return ws.ExitStatus()
    }
    return 1
}

If I remove the argument --ignore-stdin and modify the stdout & stderr to point to os.Stdout & os.Stderr and add cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin then the tools inhabits normal behavior.

[1/2] When you assign "buffers" to Stdin and Stdout fields of an exec.Cmd, its methods which run the external program arrange for the corresponding file descriptors of the spawned process be connected to pipes, with data to/from them transparently shoveled by the code in exec. This is dfferent from your Python call which makes the spawned process merely inherit the standard I/O file descriptors from the original process (and so commix ends up connected to your teminal emulator's console).

[2/2] Supposedly that's why commix fails in your setup and works when you explicitly assign os.Std* to the corresponding fields of exec.Cmd: in that case, the matching standard I/O streams of the spawned process end up connected to your terminal emulator's console, too. I think commix has some bug which makes it not work normally when it's not connected to a terminal, so I'd start with reading its source code (it's F/OSS anyway).

Please note that the programming language being discussed is called Go. The logic is generally the same as with not calling Python "PythonLang" and so on.

A program can check if a file descriptor is connected to a terminal (tty), and behave differently if so. This is common for programs that uses colored text for example. It might be interesting to se how commix behave if you pipe output to a file.

@LarsChristianJensen when output is directed to a file instead of an in memory buffer the result is the same, I get empty files.

@kosix I have opened a ticket with Commix on their github page. Btw, it Python was named "Py" I'd be calling it "Pylang". I will stick to "Golang".

Of course, you're entitled to do whatever you want as long as it does not break local law ;-) Using this naming, chances are high you will sound lame to seasoned Go devs but it's your choice anyway.
